# Nebular common sidebar footer tag does not wrap the menu items correctly

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I've tried combination of nebular documentation and ngx-admin examples to create the sidebar footer. Using the same structure design `@theme/layouts/one-column` and there I've created the sidebar-footer since it's the right place for that to display in the entire app:

```
//@theme/layouts/one-column/one-column.layouts.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-one-column-layout',
    styleUrls: ['./one-column.layout.scss'],
    template: `
        <nb-layout windowMode>
            <nb-layout-header fixed>
                <ngx-header></ngx-header>
            </nb-layout-header>
            <nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar" tag="menu-sidebar" responsive>
                <ng-content select="nb-menu"></ng-content>
                <nb-sidebar-footer>
                    <ng-content select=".nb-menu-footer"></ng-content>
                </nb-sidebar-footer>
            </nb-sidebar>
            <nb-layout-column>
                <ng-content select="router-outlet"></ng-content>
            </nb-layout-column>
            <nb-layout-footer fixed>
                <ngx-footer></ngx-footer>
            </nb-layout-footer>
        </nb-layout>
    `,
})
export class OneColumnLayoutComponent {}
```

Inside `<nb-sidebar-footer>` I've added `<ng-content select=".nb-menu-footer"></ng-content>` and then in my `pages.component.ts` I've added `nb-menu` with items attribute that represent the expected footer item:

```
// pages.component.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app-pages',
    styleUrls: ['./pages.component.scss'],
    template: `
        <ngx-one-column-layout>
            <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
            <nb-menu class=".nb-menu-footer" [items]="menuFooter"></nb-menu>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </ngx-one-column-layout>
    `,
})


menuFooter = [
  {
      title: 'О сайте',
      icon: 'heart',
      link: '/pages/imprint/overview',
      home: false,
  }
]
```

But I endet up with something like this:

[image]

How to place correctly `nb-menu` item as you can see `nb-sidebar-footer` wraps `<ng-content select=".nb-menu-footer"></ng-content>`

StackBlitz [StackBlitz Seed Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nebular-common-sidebar-footer)

**npm, node, OS, Browser**

```
node: v12.0.0
npm: 6.9.0
OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome
```

**Angular, Nebular**

```
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.3",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/localize": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.3",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.3",
"@nebular/auth": "^7.0.0",
"@nebular/eva-icons": "7.0.0",
"@nebular/security": "^7.0.0",
"@nebular/theme": "^7.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a custom component in `<nb-sidebar-footer>` tag to add footer.
like below example:

```
<nb-layout windowMode>
  <nb-layout-header fixed>
    <ngx-header></ngx-header>
  </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar" tag="menu-sidebar" responsive start>
      <ng-content select="nb-menu"></ng-content>

      <nb-sidebar-footer>
        <custom-sidebar-footer></custom-sidebar-footer>
      </nb-sidebar-footer>
  </nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>
    <ng-content select="router-outlet"></ng-content>
  </nb-layout-column>

  <nb-layout-footer fixed>
    <ngx-footer></ngx-footer>
  </nb-layout-footer>
</nb-layout>
```

and custom component for footer:

custom-footer.component.html

```
<nb-menu [items]="menuFooter"></nb-menu>
```

custom-footer.component.ts

```
  menuFooter : NbMenuItem[] = [{
     title: 'О сайте',
     icon: 'heart',
     link: '/pages/imprint/overview',
     home: false,
  }];
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach kinda works but I've to split now my menu items in two files, one menu item is defined in `export class CustomSidebarFooterComponent {` and others are in `export class PagesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {` and `CustomSidebarFooterComponent ` should me declared in `export class ThemeModule {` how could I do something like nebular done, e.g `<custom-sidebar-footer select="footer-tems"></custom-sidebar-footer>`?

Comment: I added a service and set data in pages component to subscribe Menu changes in custom-footer component, this service listen to Menu changes and depend on different events it will set menu items for menuFooter or we can clear footer items.
So we set menu item and footer item in one place but we have to use BehaviorSubject and Observable on service to notify menu item changes on custom-footer component.

Comment: Yeah, I've done it this way now and it still buggy and workaround. Selected item in footer does stay as selected even if you select another item in the main menu. Since we have now two menus. But I'll accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: We can use menuService.onItemClick().subscribe((menuItem: NbMenuBag) => {} to detect select menu items and set selected false, I think it can help.